# How to transpose the columns in a SQL select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table named `Ingresos_Ppto` with this definition:

```
ID         int       PK
IdCliente  int       
FechaPpto  Datetime
Rubro      varchar(max)
Valor      numer(18,0)
```

When I run a select statement for `IdCliente = 1`, I get this result:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    [dbo].[Ingresos_Ppto] [Y]
WHERE
    ([Y].[IdCliente] = @idc)
```

Output:

```
ID| IdCliente | FechaPpto  | Rubro                      |   Valor
+-+-----------+------------+----------------------------+--------------
1 | 1         | 2019-01-01 | Portal web WP              |   9148489.00
2 | 1         | 2019-01-01 | Portal web WP + ecommerce  |   3785304.00
3 | 1         | 2019-01-01 | Renting tecnológico        |   7223406.00
4 | 1         | 2019-01-01 | Branding                   |   3280937.00
5 | 1         | 2019-01-01 | Mercadeo y publicidad      |   3372619.00
6 | 1         | 2019-02-01 | Portal web WP              |   9172295.00
7 | 1         | 2019-02-01 | Portal web WP + ecommerce  |   9140700.00
8 | 1         | 2019-02-01 | Renting tecnológico        |   7298693.00
9 | 1         | 2019-02-01 | Branding                   |   4912017.00
```

I need to transpose the columns, so that I can get Rubro, and columns according to the date of the budget, this will be the desired output:

```
Rubro                      | 2019-01      | 2019-02    
+--------------------------+--------------+-------------
Portal web WP              | 9148489.00   | 9172295.00 
Portal web WP + ecommerce  | 3785304.00   | 9140700.00 
Renting tecnológico        | 7223406.00   | 72986693.00
Branding                   | 3280937.00   | 4912017.00
Mercadeo y publicidad      | 3372619.00   | 0.00
```

This is my code so far, but it won't run:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FechaPpto) 
                      FROM Ingresos_Ppto 
                      GROUP BY FechaPpto, id
                      ORDER BY id
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select Rubro, FechaPpto
                from Ingresos_Ppto
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Rubro)
                for FechaPpto in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   The column 'Jan  1 2019 12:00AM' was specified multiple times for 'p'

How can I rewrite the code to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Wait, in fact, remove `id` from the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses; it has no reason to be there. That's the *real* reason why you're getting the error.

Comment: That is a very different question, and should be posted as a different one (with the appropriate tags).